# Change button classes on hover in CSS only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for a simple test webapp. I want a button to start off with the standard style (`btn`), and switch to the `btn-danger` style only on hover. I know this can be done with jquery or straight javascript, but I'm really not interested in that approach.

Can I do this in straight CSS *without* copying any of the bootstrap style code into my own CSS? Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
.mybutton {

}

.mybutton:hover {
  style: btn-danger;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wPDCm/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done without a CSS pre-processor.

Using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) you could do something like:

```
@mixin danger-will-robinson {
  background-color: red;
}

.btn-danger {
  @include danger-will-robinson;
}

.mybutton:hover {
  @include danger-will-robinson;
}
```

Other CSS preprocessors have similar features.

Comment: Drat. Well, this looks like the feature I want. Guess I will have to look into these preprocessors. Thanks (will mark accepted when the silly timer lets me ><)

Comment: Except you wouldn't actually write it that way if you were using Sass.  You would use the `@extend` directive (something LESS does not have an equivalent of):  `.mybutton:hover { @extend .btn-danger }`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for using LESS (the CSS preprocessor that Twitter Bootstrap uses) should be this:

```
.mybutton:hover {
    @include .btn-danger;
}
```

There is no way to do this with CSS alone.